# Get resource id Imageview (array of ImageViews)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-xml

How do i retrieve the resource_id for an array of imageViews in android? I know how to get i for a drawable resource

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("[imagename]" + indexNumber, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

But now I want to retrieve the id for an imageView which resides in the layout-folder (activity_main.xml)

The reason is that I have 10 different imageviews with similar names except the indexnumer.

My full code

```
    ImageView[] imageView = new ImageView[10];
    AnimationDrawable[] frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        int id = ???
        imageView[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
        imageView[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gold_coin_animation);

        // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
        frameAnimation[i] = (AnimationDrawable) imageView[i].getBackground();

        frameAnimation[i].start();
    }
```

The names of the imagevies are

```
gold_coin_id1
gold_coin_id2
gold_coin_id3
...
gold_coin_id110
```

*So I want to retrieve the resource-id of the view by the prefix (gold_coin) concatenated with an indexnumber*

Comment: You can set id to the imageview lik imageViewArray[i].setId(i);

Comment: ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
            imageViewArray[i].setId(i);
        }

Comment: you can create int[] resArray = new int[]{ R.drawable.gold_coin_id1, R.drawable.gold_coin_id2, R.drawable.gold_coin_id3, R.drawable.gold_coin_id4} and use this resArray to setBackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("gold_coin_id"+i, "id", getPackageName());
imageView[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
```

Comment: stupid me - I should learn to study the signature more in the future. thanks :-)